# sqlite3 converting data into short array

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, type-conversion

I am using sqlite3 on an embedded system with Modbus. I need to pack the information from sqlite3's select statement results into an array of shorts to be able to pass over Modbus.

Currently, I am only using 2 data types from sqlite3 (TEXT and INT). I am trying to pack the results of each columns results into an array of shorts. For example:

```
typedef struct
{
    short unitSN[4];
    short unitClass[1];
}UnitSettings;

UnitSettings unitSettings;

// prepare and execute select statement for table, then put into structs members
s = sqlite3_prepare(db, sqlstmt, strlen(sqlstmt), &stmt, &pzTest);
s = sqlite3_step( stmt );

// I want to do something like this:
unitSettings.unitSN[] = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
unitSettings.unitClass[] = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 1);
```

I was thinking about creating functions to convert from unsigned  char* (result of sqlite3_column_text) to short array and int to short array. Is this the way to go about it? Or is there are proper way to cast these results on the fly?

Also, was thinking of making the structs match the sqlite3 table types for easy copying and then at the end, have a function to run through each structs members and convert it into an array of shorts at the end.

**EDIT**: I just read about unions within structs and I think this would be exactly what I need:

```
typedef struct
{
    union
    {
        unsigned char* unitSN;
        short unitSNArr[4]; 
    }

    union
    {
        int unitClass;
        short unitClassArr[1];
    }  
}UnitSettings;
```

It says that now they both look at the same piece of memory but can read it in different ways, which is what I want. This would be much easier than any kind of converting right?

Comment: Now decide... Do you have `short`s or strings?

Answer (score 0):

sqlite will not provide these conversions for you automatically.  You'd have to do the conversions yourself.

I would just use plain text access, and then write free functions to translate access to the short. Something like this, not really sure what would interface would make the most sense per your access.

```
void read_short(const char* data, size_t index, short& val) {
  val = *(reintepret_cast<short*>(&data[index*2]));
}
```

Maybe your use case already has them in arrays of shorts or something? I'd probably still only do one short per field if that's actually how you use the data.

Personally, I would just put them into the database as integers if you can help it.  You'd have to write special tools just to look at the database values, which isn't exactly friendly for maintenance.